# How to implement a recursive scheme in time series forecasting using R?

Tags: r, recursion, time-series, forecasting

```
##load the data
ausbeer
##Train set
train <- ausbeer
##Fit model
m <- Arima(train,order = c(1,1,1))
forecast_length <- 12
fcst <- ts(,start = c(2010,3),frequency = 4)
##loop
for (i in forecast_length) {
  m <- Arima(train,order = c(1,1,1))
  fcst[i] <- predict(m,n.ahead = 1)$pred
  train <- ts(c(train,fcst[i]))
  
}
```

The problem lies here: In the above code, I try to add the new forecasted value to the train set to form a new time series, then forecast it again in a recursive way. However, whenever I add the first prediction to the train set, the loop will stop at:

```
fcst[i] <- predict(m,n.ahead = 1)$pred
```

with an error:

> Error in `[<-.ts`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 423.107159839553) : only replacement of elements is allowed.

I don't quite get it here since the new data has been transformed into a ts object, the model works as well, why the `predict()` cannot be applied?

Comment: Welcome to SO 邢予诚. Please review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), particularly the part about making a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can make a small sample of your data and then use dput() and copy the result into your question. If your data are confidential, you can just make an example dataset that has a similar structure to your real dataset. Thanks